# ListView dinâmica com checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Como adicionar checkboxes em itens de uma lista dinâmica? Estou desenvolvendo um app de frequência escolar e essa é a minha classe pra adicionar os alunos:

```
public class AddAluno extends AppCompatActivity {

BancoAlunos bancoAlunos;
EditText digitarAluno;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addaluno);

    final ListView listV = findViewById(R.id.list);
    digitarAluno = findViewById(R.id.digitaraluno);
    ImageButton addEstudante = findViewById(R.id.addestudante);
    bancoAlunos = new BancoAlunos(this);

    //toolbar com seta para voltar para a tela inicial
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //lista de alunos
    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = bancoAlunos.getListContents();

    //se o banco de alunos estiver vazio, retornar msg. Se nao, mostrar lista
    if (data.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Este grupo está vazio! :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
            listV.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }

    //adicionar nome à lista quando o botao for clicado
    addEstudante.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newEntry = digitarAluno.getText().toString();
            if (digitarAluno.length() != 0) {
                AddAlunos(newEntry);
                digitarAluno.setText("");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AddAluno.this, "Digite o nome do aluno", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

//add nome ao banco
public void AddAlunos(String newEntry) {

    boolean addAlunos = bancoAlunos.addData(newEntry);

    if (addAlunos) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Aluno adicionado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Algo deu errado! :( Tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Basicamente o usuário digita o nome do aluno, clica no botão "adicionar" e voilà, o nome é adicionado ao banco e a lista com os itens aparece abaixo do EditText (cadastro). Para isso, usei uma lista dinâmica, na qual começa vazia e o usuário vai incrementando.

Agora quero fazer com que toda vez que o usuário vá adicionar mais um item na lista, ele já apareça com um checkbox do lado. Alguém sabe como resolver? Já procurei em alguns lugares, mas não entendi muito o que devo fazer/adicionar ao código.

Comment: Você está usando o SQLite para gravar os registros correto !? Você quer gerar uma listView, com esses registros, e ao lado de cada um, ter uma checkbox para selecioná-los e após essa seleção, executar uma rotina para com esses registros selecionados, é isso ?

Comment: Vc precisa fazer um adapter e um layout para o item da lista, no qual vc vai por o checkbox e um textview por exemplo.

https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial